# PHP if statement "broken" when checking on row

Tags: php, mysql, pointers, if-statement, types

I can't get an IF-statement to do the "right" thing, the code;

```
public function getUID($email)
{
    $query = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $query->execute(array($email));

    $row = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    alert($row, true);           // array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "0" }
    alert(is_array($row), true); // bool(true)
    alert($row == false, true);  // bool(false)
    if( $row == false ) {
        // Here we are!
        return false;
    }

    return $row['id'];
}
```

For some reason the if-statement thinks the result is true, and I can't understand why :[] The output from the sql-command seems correct, we should get an id-entry that is 0...

When writing this question I thought about dropping this question and comparing $row to NULL instead. but that isn't helping. It still goes to return false...

Comment: What is the exact value of `$row`?  Seems likely it's a "truthy" value, which makes me think you need a different condition in your if, which sounds like what you're thinking too.

Comment: What is the `alert` function?

Comment: @aynber alert just does `var_dump` wrapped in a `<div class="alert">` thing. Makes it easier to read. the `true` flag is for toggling 'var_dump' or 'print' :P

Comment: You're testing whether the $row is a value, not whether you have a value in $row['id']. $row is an array - so it's not false. $row['id'] is 0 and would test as false.

Comment: @flip I agree, it is not false. and so it shouldn't run the code inside the if-statment, but it does :/ When no record is found the row should be either false or NULL.

Comment: My apologies, I misread the question.

Comment: Wait, how do you know it's running the if statement? It's going to return false, or it's going to return the id of 0. Both evaluate as false if using just two equal signs, outside of your function.  Verify which it's hitting by adding another alert within the if statement, and one after it, like `alert('inside the if');` and `alert('did not hit if');`

Comment: as @aynber stated, there is nothing broken, your code will never enter that IF if your query returns at least one result

Comment: Thanks guys, it ain't got anything to do with this method. It's because "0" is treated as false...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` is obviously not broken, and there is nothing wrong with this method. As pointed out by @aynber PHP treats `"0"` as `false` when using `==` to compare things. And outside this method I had a test that checked wether it returned `false`, if not I was happy and thought "it returned the ID from the database.

Therefore, the simple solution was to do this check with `===`. Comparing both type and value.